# draw color scale in grid plot in r

Tags: r, colors, fill, r-grid

I want to plot color scale with grid package. Something like heat.plot (10).

[image]

I am trying something like this:

```
require(grid)
legendViewport <- viewport(height=0.3, width=0.8)
pushViewport(legendViewport)
grid.rect(gp = gpar(col = "gray90"))
```

Let's say I want to divide 0 to 1, into 10 and fill heat.colors (10). Is there a simple way to do it.

Comment: `grid.raster(heat.colors (10))`

Comment: try [this one](https://gist.github.com/3202137) maybe, or browse the source code of lattice or ggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want colors,

```
grid.raster(t(heat.colors (10)), 
   width=unit(1,"npc"),
   height=unit(1,"npc"), int=FALSE)
```